# Solutions to determine if a person is famous/notorious with a score

Tags: algorithm, deep-learning, ranking

It's clear that determine if a person is famous isn't easy and is mainly a question of personal bias but I'm sure that integrating different data sources is possible to extract some kind of objective insight on this. Does someone knowns if someone has already built an algorithm, a network, or an API to be used to define if a person is famous/notorious?

Comment: 1. Google persons name with `"` 2. Check how many results google has on that person

Comment: Yes, this was one of the options, but think It's not enough to determine celebrity. There are a lot of social influencers that are not on google but have a lot of followers. Also this is a sort of celebrity. Thank you for your answer.